# Mysql selecting something as something else

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select something as something else, but for some reason it's always just 0 words, even though it shows 2 results when I'm not trying to select it as words. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT (
responseX REGEXP  '^ cats[[:>:]]'
) AS words
FROM  `allData`
```

Comment: Where's the php? Have you tried running this in just a mysql shell?

Comment: Add examples of table data and expected result. Withour it question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), `REGEXP` can output `0` or `1`:

> Returns 1 if expr matches pat; otherwise it returns 0.

So I've no idea what you were doing, that it displayed `2` as output.

Comment: He got 2 results as output, not `2`